# Allow this precompiled site to be updatable Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We used Visual Studio 2010 and when we exported the website, we used the option to remove the check "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable". In that way it exported just the website but without the source code from Visual Studio 2019 where is this option? We can't find it.

We see only the exported site but it has all the source and modifiable as if was checked by default the option "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" we need to uncheck that option to avoid is updatable. Where can I disable that option in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a publish - but to a local folder.

So from the menu choose build->publish "my site".

And then from that choose start-> and then choose Folder.

That will result in a published site in a folder. There will of course be the compiled code in the "bin" folder - but you could if for some reason simply delete that folder (but it would and is required to run). It also rather possible you are confusing that of a web site vs that of a web site application. A web site does not need to compile, and the server will compile on the fly. But if you created a web application (as opposed to a site), then it is pre-compiled into the bin folder and is required. its been some time, but this process was quite much the same in 2010. (eg; the difference between having created a web site vs that of a web application).

so quite sure this process was the same as back then. The major difference (back then or even now) is you having created a web site in VS as opposed to a web application. Quite sure that same difference and same behaviors you see remain in place today.

Regardless of web site vs web application in VS? A web publish will produce just the web pages without the code behind parts.

Comment: I only have the option to publish the webb app. In VS 2010 when we used the check we mentioned in the main files we had: “This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!“. All was very pretty in 2010 hidden as you see. Now in 2019 with the option to publish web app always publish with al the free code visible everywhere... In the bin file we don’t see the DLL’s VS 2010 created all is weak in 2019. How can we hide all code as we did with 2010 with that simply check? We are using same web app of 2010 and 2010 publish pretty check in the check but not 2019.

Comment: I found the check of updatable or not. Is in the export recompile configure options. Thank you anyway. It worked now.